# Color only specific string of Console.Writeline when inserting an array

Tags: c#, arrays, colors

If I have this code:

```
Array[1] = "stackoverflower"; 
Array[2] = "friend"; 
Array[3] = "howsitgoin"; 

Console.WriteLine(@"Hello {0}, {1}, {2} with you", Array)
```

Can I make it so that the word friend is RED while the rest is black (without splitting the sentences up, because I have a situation in which that is not practical at all).

Comment: No, you have to change the color then write what you want in the color then change it back and continue writing.  Maybe you can show the situation where it's not practical instead.

Comment: Is this truly a console app? Or are you "sandboxing" code to test it, with the end result being cshtml or WinForms? I ask because changing color on console is much different than other apps. If this is "sandbox" then you are wasting your time with a console app.

Comment: @RobJansen Did you solve the problem? If yes then please accept the answer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to something like this if you want to use console output. You have to split the sentences because there aren't any other way to do that in console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array = new string[] { "stackoverflower", "friend", "howsitgoin" };

    Console.Write("Hello ");
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (item.Equals("friend"))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
        }
    }
    Console.Write("with you");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```